# Forgot lock screen PIN on child phone with Family Link, can't figure out how to get into it or reset PIN

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, google-family-link

My child forgot her lock screen PIN and I use Family Link, but I can't figure out how to get into it or reset the PIN through the app.

What are my options?

Comment: https://support.google.com/families/answer/7307262

Answer (score 0):

If she does not have anything important on it, you can try factory resetting it.

WARNING: This will erase everything on the phone except Android.

First you need to get to the system recovery screen, here's how:

According to the [LG User Manual/System recovery page](https://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/VS985/Userguide/097.html)

> Turn the phone off. Press and hold the following keys at the same time: Volume Down Key + Power/Lock Key for approximately 10 seconds. Release both of the keys when the System recovery screen is displayed.

In order to navigate here, since touchscreen does not work here:

Use the volume up key to go up, the volume down key to go down and power button to click.

1 - Select "Factory reset" (may be written differently depending on your device model).

2 - Click it.

3 - Wait for it to erase everything on the phone.

After that, it will ask you to do the first use setup again.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to recover it. If there is stuff on it that she doesnt want to lose then just try some numbers.

- She can start with usual pins she would use, with a digit either side of each number. Then birthday related days.
- Or just try all numbers in sequence. If she is dedicated, she could try 500 pins an hour. Thats 20 hours for all combinations. An hour a day is 20 days.

Comment: question is about family link. are you sure there is no way to recover?