# How can I unlock my child's phone using Family Link?

Tags: google-family-link

My daughter has a Samsung S21 and I set family link for it. Is there any way to unlock the screen PIN of the phone using family link without resetting the whole phone?

Thanks.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to get into my child's Family Link phone after forgotten password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250079/44325), [Forgot lock screen PIN on child phone with Family Link, can't figure out how to get into it or reset PIN](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253600/44325)