# Unlock Samsung pattern lock using Family Link

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, locked-out, google-family-link

How do I unlock my son's Samsung Galaxy S20 pattern lock using Family Link?

I tried the hard reset option but couldn't get to factory reset. The phone keeps throwing the message to unlock the pattern. I cannot try using a Google account as he is logged in using a child's email account.

Could anyone please help me? I had used my WhatsApp number on his phone, but now I can't get my WhatsApp because of this issue.

Comment: If you have a samsung too, then put your sons Sim in your phone. Log into whatsapp and change it to your number.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to get into my child's Family Link phone after forgotten password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250079/44325), [Forgot lock screen PIN on child phone with Family Link, can't figure out how to get into it or reset PIN](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253600/44325)